# During testing the logging part of Cypress disappears

Tags: cypress

During my test run I need to open Stripe to add user's data.
But this page breaks the Cypress logging tab, and input selection doesn't work.

Cypress view for test
[image]

After Stripe open
[image]

In my case after clicking on button in our app, user goes to Stripe page. I use this code:

```
    cy.xpath('//button[contains(text(), "Next")]').click()
    
    cy.get("#cardNumber").type("4242424242424242");
    cy.get("#cardCvc").type("123");
    cy.get("#cardExpiry").type(
      "12" + (new Date().getFullYear() + 10).toString().substr(-2)
    );
```

How to fix view?

Answer (score 0):

One major pain point when using Cypress is testing on elements within iframes. Unfortunately, Cypress can’t easily target elements within an iframe without a bit of extra work. You need to wrap iframe into cypress.

```
 // Enter card details in to Stripe iframe fields
cy
  .get('iframe')
  .its('0.contentDocument.body').should('not.be.empty')
  .then(cy.wrap)
  .find('#cardNumber')
  .type('4242424242424242')

cy
  .get('iframe')
  .its('1.contentDocument.body').should('not.be.empty')
  .then(cy.wrap)
  .find('card expire class or id')
  .type('1225') //example expire date

cy
  .get('iframe')
  .its('2.contentDocument.body').should('not.be.empty')
  .then(cy.wrap)
  .find('#cardCvc')
  .type('123')

// Click the button to submit the page
cy.get('your button class').click()
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Perhaps, I pasted the code you wrote here. Perhaps, I need to put my values.

Comment: This payment page is not as `iframe`. Perhaps, there is another solution